Get/set в классах
Есть класс MyClass(). 
Для геттеров есть декоратор @property, но для сеттеров - @prop_name.setter.
Почему именно так?

Потому что декоратор @property добавляет дополнительную функциональность в первый метод (добавляет возможность по имени метода без скобок вызывать этот метод, и добавляет поле setter в метод), и эта функциональность позволяет использовать уже этот setter из метода как декоратор

getter: метод, который позволяет вам получить доступ к атрибуту
в данном классе.
setter: метод, который позволяет вам устанавливать или изменять
значение атрибута в классе.
Вы определяете методы getter и setter для атрибутов. 
Обычно метод getter возвращают значение целевого атрибута,
а методы setter принимают новое значение
и присваивают его базовому атрибуту.
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self._text = text

    def get_text(self):
        return self._text

    def set_text(self, value):
        
        self._text = value.upper()  

print()     
myClass = MyClass('Hello')
print(f'1 {myClass.get_text()}') 

myClass.set_text('Hello u111')
print(f'2 {myClass.get_text()}') 
print()



В Python, способ привязать поведение к атрибуту -
превратить сам атрибут в свойство. 
Свойства объединяют методы для получения, установки
и документирования базовых данных.
Следовательно, свойства - это специальные атрибуты
с дополнительным поведением.
Вы можете использовать свойства так же, как и обычные атрибуты. 
Когда вы получаете доступ к свойству, автоматически вызывается
прикрепленный к нему метод получения. 
Аналогично, когда вы изменяете свойство, вызывается его метод установки.
Такое поведение предоставляет средства для придания функциональности
вашим атрибутам без внесения критических изменений в ваш код.
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    @property
    def text(self):
        return self._text

    @text.setter
    def text(self, value):
        self._text = value.upper()  
        
myClass = MyClass('Hello')
print(f'3 {myClass.text}') 

myClass.text = 'Hello u111'
print(f'4 {myClass.text}') 


